# How to mute the warning of "never mutated" in Swift?

Tags: swift, var, let

**Regarding duplicate flag:** This question is different from the flagged question as I am asking about how to mute the warnings as I was not aware of the concept of Swift. The provided below answer helps me understand the very basic nature of Swift. Thus this question should not flagged as duplicate.

---

I have a class name Person having following variables.

```
private var _id:String = ""
var id:String {
    get {
        return _id
    }
    set (newId) {
        _id = newId
    }
}

private var _name:String = ""
var name:String {
    get {
        return _name
    }
    set (newName) {
        _name = newName
    }
}

private var _signedDate:Date? = nil
var signedDate:Date {
    get {
        return _signedDate!
    }
    set(newDate) {
        _signedDate = newDate
    }
}
```

These private var's are going to update with a setter.

So while creating an object for the `Person` class, I am writing this code.

```
var p1 = Person()
p1.id = "1"
p1.name = "Hemang"

array.append(p1)
```

Maybe later, I will update the value of signedDate with a setter.

So I should not create this object with `let`.

However, it's showing me this warning:

> Variable 'p1' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant.

How to mute this warning?

Please let me know if you need more information on this.

Comment: Why don't you show your setter?

Comment: the warning is kind of self-explanatory

Comment: Google for "Swift3 value vs reference type" to learn more.

Comment: Not related but private backing variables with custom setters and getters are nonsense in Swift. This is not (Objective-)C.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Because actually you don't change the `Person` object,
 With `let` you can change the `properties` of the object. But you can't change the `object` it self.

So change your code to what the warning lead you.

> *And of course you can try before asking this question.*

Comment: Thanks, Hamed,  you have cleared a deep doubt of Swift to me. I thought we can't change the member variables of a constant object of a class.

Comment: @Hemang You can't change the properties of a constant struct, but you can for a class as long as you don't change the reference itself (that is, you can change any of the object's properties but you can't point it to a different object).  That's one of the differences between value types and reference types.